# Nested loop and list comrehension for removing digits from list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension, nested-loops

I have a list of "sentences"(having 3000 strings) like below:

```
sentences[0:5]

['So there is no way for me to plug it in here in the US unless I go by a converter.',
 'Good case, Excellent value.',
 'Great for the jawbone.',
 'Tied to charger for conversations lasting more than 45 minutes.MAJOR PROBLEMS!!',
 'The mic is great.']
```

I want to remove digits from each string in this list. e.g. "45" in 4th string in above example.

When I use nested loops, it doesn't give the desired result. Rather it repeats each string sentence equal to the number of digits in the "digits" list as shown below:

```
digits=[str(i) for i in range(0,10)]    
t=[]    
for i in sentences:    
    for j in digits:    
        a=i.replace(j,'')    
        t.append(a)    
print(t[0:5])

['So there is no way for me to plug it in here in the US unless I go by a converter.', 'So there is no way for me to plug it in here in the US unless I go by a converter.', 'So there is no way for me to plug it in here in the US unless I go by a converter.', 'So there is no way for me to plug it in here in the US unless I go by a converter.', 'So there is no way for me to plug it in here in the US unless I go by a converter.']
```

However, when I create a function and then call it in list comprehension, it works perfectly as shown below:

```
def full_remove(x,remove_list):    
    for i in remove_list:    
        x=x.replace(i,' ')    
    return x

digits=[str(x) for x in range(10)]    
digit_less=[full_remove(i,digits) for i in sentences]    
print(digit_less[0:5])

['So there is no way for me to plug it in here in the US unless I go by a converter.', 'Good case, Excellent value.', 'Great for the jawbone.', 'Tied to charger for conversations lasting more than    minutes.MAJOR PROBLEMS!!', 'The mic is great.']
```

As far as I understand, here logic of calling function in list comprehension is same as using nested loop but then why nested loop not working? Where am I making mistake?

Please explain.

Thanks

Comment: Think carefully: for each of the sentences in the original list, how many modified sentences should be appended to the output list? Now, how many times are you seeing it actually happen in the first case? Can you think of a reason for that? Consider carefully the part of your code that does the appending. How many times will it be called? You will get a clearer picture if you start with a shorter version of `sentences`, but display the entire output (instead of a slice) for your debugging.

Comment: (But once you fix it, please stick with the version that uses comprehensions. This is a better way to organize your code; you separate the responsibility for fixing a sentence, from the responsibility for iterating over the input.)

Comment: Thanks for responding Karl. I have checked that it does remove the digit in the string when iterator comes to that digit which string has. But then it continues to append string until all the numbers in the "digit" list are iterated. I have 10 digits in the "digits" list (from 0 to 9) so it is iterating and appending each string 10 times.

Comment: Yes; now, can you think of a reason why it keeps appending that string, 10 times? Hint: how many digits are in the `digits` list?

Comment: Yes, because digits has len(digits)=10. Now, how can I solve it? I am not able to think. Sorry I am bit new to pyhton.

Comment: Yes, now why does it append a separate time for each of the digits? Hint: where in the code is the `append` call, and how is it indented? I ask these questions because *if you expect to learn Python (or any other programming language), you need to be able to solve problems for yourself*, by analyzing the situation carefully.

Comment: Thank you Karl :)  I am able to stop repetitions now by removing the unnecessary indentation of append. However, I am yet to figure out what do I need to change in the nested loop to remove the digits from each string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216314/discussion-between-deepak-dhiman-and-karl-knechtel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in the first case is with your indenting.

In the nested loop approach:
- for every sentence
- loop through every digit and replace it
- append the sentence each time

That results in each sentence being appended 10 times, since there are 10 digits to loop through in the inner loop [0,9].

Instead, you can fix that, just by appending a only once. If you write the loop like this, it should fix your issue:

```
for i in sentences:    
    for j in digits:    
        i=i.replace(j,'')    
    t.append(i)
```

Note the indenting of the append statement.

This now only appends the sentence into the t list, once all digits are removed, not every time you loop through a digit

You can clean this up a lot, but in relation to the question you've asked, that's how to correct the bug you have.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I tried what you suggested. In that case, digits are not removed however repetitions in the end result has stopped. Now it appends only the last value after the inside loop is finished. Now I need to figure out, why digits are not being removed.

Comment: Did you also change 'a' to 'i'? Numbers will be removed fine.
The reason you need to do that, is that a is set back to i with 1 digit removed (if present) each time. So if digit 9 is not in the string, just the full i (with numbers) is appended.
By replacing the digits in i each loop, you don't throw away the removals you've already made.

Answer (score 0):

A regex based solution would probably be preferable here:

```
digit_less = [re.sub(r'\s*\d+\s*', ' ', i).strip() for i in sentences]
print(digit_less)
```

This prints:

```
   ['So there is no way for me to plug it in here in the US unless I go by a converter.',
    'Good case, Excellent value.',
    'Great for the jawbone.',
    'Tied to charger for conversations lasting more than minutes.MAJOR PROBLEMS!!',
    'The mic is great.']
```

This approach replaces all digits and surrounding whitespace with just a single space.  The call to `strip()` removes any leading/trailing whitespace which might result as a side effect.

Comment: The real question here is not for a completely different solution, but he wants an explanation on how his one solution works, while other does not.